# PHP HTML shopping cart - remove added, first product isn't showing

Tags: php, html

I made a shopping cart for people to order products. The products are added perfect. So i made a 'remove' button. But since i implemented the 'remove' button, the first result is not showing. The second and third are showing up. What am I doing wrong?

```
//add function // 
if(isset($_POST["add"])){                                                    
  if (isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
      $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "SKU");
     
      if(!in_array($_GET["SKU"], $item_array_id)){
          $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
          
          $item_array = array(
             'SKU' => $_GET["SKU"], 
             'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"], 
             'quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
             'item_description' => $_POST["hidden_description"]
          ); 

          $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array; 
          echo '<script> window.location="lijstweergave.php"</script>'; 
      }
       else{
        echo '<script>alert("Product is already added to cart")</script>'; 
        echo '<script>window.location="lijstweergave.php"</script>';  
      }
    } else{
      $item_array = array(    'SKU' => $_GET["SKU"], 
                              'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"], 
                              'quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
                              'item_description' => $_POST["hidden_description"]
                            ); 

    $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;   
    }    
}


//remove deel. ////Something wrong here?? // 
if (isset($_POST['remove_item'])) {
    $remove_SKU = $_POST['remove_SKU'];
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['SKU'] == $remove_SKU) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array_values($_SESSION['cart']);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by implementing the remove button, all I can see in your script is a commented form, are you saying that it works fine with the form commented, but as soon as you uncomment it stops working?

Comment: It could be due to an issue with the loop that generates the table rows. The loop iterates over the $_SESSION['cart'] array and generates a table row for each element in the array. It is possible that there is an off-by-one error in the loop that is causing an extra row to be generated. You could try checking the loop to make sure that it is iterating over the correct number of elements.  I think it's something like this... But don't know how to solve...

Comment: @Merijndk Yes, exactly, the second and third and following are showing up, but the first one disappears. Only the remove button is showing.

Comment: (Unrelated?) fyi: `<form>` inside `<tr>` isn't allowed. Place your form in its own `<tr><td>...</td></tr>`.

Comment: Ok, one problem I see is that you try to render the form in a `<tr>`. That is not possible as far as I know since its just a container for td items. Try to put a `<td>` around the form?

Comment: I added the <td> elements, but the problem remains :-(..

Comment: There seems to be no problem with your code. I created a online code tester: https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/0a65c4a that works fine, I manually filled the `$SESSION['cart']`. as you can see it renders the table as expected.

Comment: Thanks! nice tester. So the problem must be somewhere else... the debugging goes on..

Comment: The script you added now has some wierd issues. For instance the if statement on line 3 has no brackets etc. So its hard to see what is going on in this that script.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the items into the array at the last position using COUNT.

Suppose you have 4 items

item1
item2
item3
item4

If the accounts are 4 items so when adding another it is added

Item 5

Now we delete item 1

it would stay like that

item2
item3
item4
item5

When you go to add a new item it should be item 6

but how do you add it based on the number of existing items and now there are only 4 again

it adds it back to you in position 5

To avoid this change

$_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;

By

$_SESSION["cart"][] = $item_array;

This way it will always add the item in the last position of the array

I have translated the answer with google, sorry if it is not understood very well

Let me know if it helped you

Comment: i already had solved the problem a slighty different way. But thanks for the input!